# 32 bit server CD fails with package corrupt

Tags: 12.04, server

Why does the CD check out but the base install says its corrupt?
I downloaded it twice and burned 3 different disks

Comment: Could you provide some more details and explain the exact commands that your ran into and the exact error messages that you encountered? That would go a long way in helping us help you. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it could be your CD-ROM that reads badly.

Answer (score 0):

Try a different download mirror. Try comparing the checksum on your ISO before burning it. If those check out clean, you probably have a hardware failure. You might be able to get away with just burning the disc on another machine since burning tends be a little more fragile than reading.

Comment: Could you provide instructions on how to change your download mirror, or checking the checksum of the ISO?